# Simulate UNIX rename() with Win32 MoveFileEx() for directories

Tags: unix, winapi, movefileex

I want to simulate a specific case of the UNIX `rename()` function to rename directories. Its MAN page specifies:

> oldpath can specify a directory. In this case, newpath must either not exist, or it must specify an empty directory.

I want to simulate the last case:

> newpath exists and is empty.

So I have created the directories `foo_dir` and `bar_dir` and called `MoveFileEx()` in order to rename `foo_dir` to `bar_dir`. Here is the code without error management:

```
mkdir("foo_dir");
mkdir("bar_dir");
MoveFileEx("foo_dir", "bar_dir", MOVEFILE_REPLACE_EXISTING)
```

But `MoveFileEx()` always fails with error 5 (access denied). I have tried with other flags for `MoveFileEx()` without success.

Must I manually remove `bar_dir` if it exists and is empty before calling `MoveFileEx()`? Or is there another solution?

I have not tried `ReplaceFile()` yet.

Comment: Remove the directory, and then call `MoveFile`.

Comment: At a low level in the filesystem, setting the [`FileRenameInformation`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff540344) fails when the target is a directory, a read-only file, or a currently executing file. For example, we see this in the sample fastfat driver in [`FatSetRenameInfo`](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/blob/master/filesys/fastfat/fileinfo.c#L3306). NTFS fails with `STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED` in this case, but FAT fails with `STATUS_OBJECT_NAME_COLLISION`, which becomes WinAPI `ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS`.

Comment: @David ok, thank you